# "data-dismiss" do modal Bootstrap bugando com o position="absolute"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, modal

Estou adicionando um botão de fechar personalizando no `modal` do bootstrap.

Quero ele na direita do `modal`, para isso eu dei um `position: absolute` e modifiquei o `top` e `right` dele.

O problema é que ao fazer isso o botão se torna inutilizável. Pelo que pude perceber, há um conflito entre o `data-dismiss: modal` (atributo que faz o elemento fechar o modal) com o `position: absolute`.

Tentei outras formas de fazer esse tal "botão" como importar um .svg, criar um `<button>`, `<span>` além de trocar o `position: absolute` pelo `float:right`.
Ao fazer isso, apenas uma pequena porção da área do botão se torna o link de fechar e não a área toda. A experiência no mobile e no desktop é bastante desagradável pois é necessário apertar/clicar diversas vezes até encontrar a área correta, sendo que o correto é TODA a área do botão ser um link para fechar o `modal`.

Segue o código e um Snippet para ficar mais claro:

```css
.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  /* REMOVA O `POSITION` E O 'BOTÃO' FUNCIONA */
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: transparent;
  right: 35px;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer
}
.close-modal:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}
.lr {
  height: 75px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1051;
}
.rl {
  height: 75px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 1051;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<a href="#modal" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
             CHAMAR MODAL    
</a>



<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
      <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <p>CONTEÚDO MODAL CONTEÚDO MODAL</p>

            <p>CONTEÚDO MODAL CONTEÚDO MODAL</p>

            <p>CONTEÚDO MODAL CONTEÚDO MODAL</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como posso solucionar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insira a propriedade **z-index** para definir ordem dos elementos de posição (relativos, absolutos e fixos)

```
.close-modal {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Resolveu! Muito obrigado. Bem simples

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de `position:absolute`, use `float:right`, e `margin-right` e `margin-top`, ao invés de `right e top`.